# Removing selected regression lines from plots made with sjPlot

Tags: r, ggplot2, sjplot

I am trying to plot an interaction plot using the `sjPlot` package with the following code:

```
model <-lm(score ~ var1 + var2 + var3 + var4 + var1*var2,data=mydata)
plot1 <- plot_model(model,type="int",ci.lvl=NA, title="", legend.title="",
  axis.title=c("var2","score"))
```

The data I'm using is similar to this dataframe:

```
n <- 50
mydata<- data.frame(
  ID = 1:n,
  var1 = sample(c("rank1", "rank2", "rank3"), n, replace = TRUE),
  var2 = sample(0:2, n, replace = TRUE),
  var3 = runif(n, min = 1, max = 60),
  var4 = sample(c(0, 1), n, replace = TRUE)
)
```

Here are the first 10 rows:

```
   ID  var1 var2      var3 var4
1   1 rank2    0 11.252379    1
2   2 rank1    1 29.954015    0
3   3 rank2    2 42.397683    1
4   4 rank1    1 12.917567    1
5   5 rank3    1  8.095043    1
6   6 rank1    0 25.986603    0
7   7 rank3    2 10.349064    0
8   8 rank1    1 35.423613    1
9   9 rank2    0 24.232398    1
10 10 rank1    2 12.996389    1
```

`var1` has 3 categories (rank1, rank2, rank3), so the interaction plot has 3 lines (`score` on the y-axis and `var2` on the x-axis). I want to remove the line representing rank2 only, so the remaining plot will only have 2 lines.

TYIA

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?

Comment: You could use the `get_model_data` function to get the interaction plot dataframe, then filter out the groups you don't want, then plot it however you like.  If you share some data we could illustrate that.

Comment: @GeorgeSavva Thanks! Which argument in `get_model_data` should I use to filter out the groups I don't want? I tried using `rm.terms` but it doesn't seem to be working

Comment: `get_model_data` just extracts the dataset.  you can then use `subset` to remove the data you don't want to show.  if you post some example data I can show you.

Comment: @GeorgeSavva I posted the dataframe I'm using

Comment: I found in the documentation for `plot_model` how to control the terms directly..  see answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used `type="pred"` rather than `type="int"` because it allows better control.  You can then specify which is the term for the `x` axis, and which term (at which levels) to use as the moderator.  See below:

```
plot_model(model,
                    type="pred",
                    ci.lvl=NA, 
                    title="", 
                    legend.title="",
                    axis.title=c("var2","score"),
                    terms=c("var2","var1 [rank2,rank3]")
                    )
```

[image]